# Symfony: Overriding/Adding routes from inherited bundle

Tags: symfony, inheritance, routes, bundle

Suppose i have a few sites that share around 80% of their functionality, including things like routing strategy, templates,etc.
I'd like to use the same codebase for all them, and have a "DefaultSiteBundle", and several "SiteABundle","SiteBBundle"  overriding or adding functionality to the DefaultSiteBundle using bundle inheritance.

This means, the DefaultSiteBundle should always be loaded, and, depending on the domain name, load SiteABundle or SiteBBundle conditionally.

My problem is, how do i manage routes, without adding all SiteBundles to app/config/routing.yml?

Comment: If it's only the routing you can use the [`hostname_pattern`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) option in your routes, but if you want to have completely different applications then you can use [multiple kernels](http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2)

Comment: Since your question is about how to handle routes, I assume you already know how to load bundle conditionally based on the hostname. How do you do that? I'm asking because the answer to your main question may depend on this.

Comment: I load the bundle conditionally using the registerBundles method in AppKernel, based on the "domain.name" environment variable.But, still, it's supposed that all routes are loaded from what's configured in app/config/routes.yml , this is, i'd have to explicitly add all the "site" bundles there, even if i'm not going to load them all.What happens with routes of not registered bundles?Hmm..I didnt test that

Answer (score 1):

The way i've solved it, in the end, was using a custom router, based on the [Advanced loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) explained in the symfony docs.The router loads and merges routes from both bundles.
It's also important to create separate caches for each site (overriding "getCacheDir" in AppKernel so it returns a different path for each domain)